# R: subset() function altered character data into strange code

Tags: r, excel, character, subset, data-conversion

i read some data into R with the `read.xlsx()` in `openxlsx` package, and here's my code for reading the data:

```
data_all = read.xlsx(xlsxFile = paste0(path, EoLfileName), sheet = 1, detectDates = T, skipEmptyRows = F)
```

now, when i access one name cell in my data, it will print the name in characters:

```
> data_all[1,'name']
[1] "76-ES+ADVIP-20G"
```

now, lets say i want to subset out some rows based on a condition on another colum:

```
data_sub = subset(data_all, !is.na(data_all$amount))
```

however, then if i print this subset data, i'd get:

```
> data_sub[1,'name']
[1] "A94198.10"
```

i've also tried to do subsetting using the following method:

```
data_sub = data_all[!is.na(data_all$amount),]
```

but i get the same thing: the expected output of "76-ES+ADVIP-20G" would be turned into "A94198.10"

I've checked many times with `mode()` and `str()` for `data_all$name` and `data_sub$name`, both return character, so they are in correct format.

here's a link to smaple data to play with:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwIbultIWxeVY1VtdDU5NFp1Tkk/view?usp=sharing

Please please help me! I am quite stuck, and i dont see other posts with similar problem. 
Why is this happeneing? subsetting shouldnt change data formatting correct?
Thank you in advance for your help!

**additional note (if its helpful):**
so when i tried to debug, i noticed that, when i was viewing the data_all in RStudio, and if i copy and paste the name "76-ES+ADVIP-20G" into the filter bar, it actually cannot find it; i'd have to type in "76-ES" and as soon as i type in the next character which is "+", RStudio data view filter would say "no matching records found"

Comment: Alright, I have to admit, this is pretty interesting. It would be really helpful, though, if you could supply a reproductable, minimal example, cause I cannot replicate it. Could you maybe use dput(head(data_all)) and paste the output here? This will allow us to have the exact same data set as yours (but only the first 6 rows).

Comment: @Laterow hi! strangely enough, i spent lots of time trying to reproduce this kind problem with seudo data, but i couldnt! the ones i create would behave as i expected. thus i did not post any data...

Comment: @Laterow the output for dput(head(data_all)) is: > dput(head(ESCEoLwSW))
structure(list(Product.ID = c("068VD-BULK", "068VD/10", "079NK", 
"10000-1P2-1AC", "10000-1P2-1AC-122", "10000-1P2-1AC-RF"), End.of.Sale.Date = c(37560, 
37560, 37416, 40208, 41059, 41668), Last.Ship.Date = c(NA, NA, 
"37506", "40299", "41149", "41758")), .Names = c("Product.ID", 
"End.of.Sale.Date", "Last.Ship.Date"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: well. the data_all is a pseudo name i used for this question, its actually "ESCEoLwSW" as you see above.

Comment: Why would you expect `data_sub[3, 'name']` to be the same as `data_all[3, 'name']`? What about `idx <- !is.na(data_all$height); data_all[idx[which(idx)[3]],'name']`?

Comment: hi @MichaelChirico im just using 3 as an example; hypothetically lets say if the first 3 data are same in data_all and data_sub. this is just some example im giving. not the real data. my point is, that the data changed its format when i subset it.

Comment: Well, did you use `data_sub = subset(ESCEoLwSW, !is.na(ESCEoLwSW$Last.Ship.Date))`? Because in that case @MichaelChirico is right. Otherwise, I can't seem to replicate your problem. It's kind of important to be able to replicate it, or else it's hard to figure out a cause :)

Comment: @Laterow so i checked (manually) by viewing ESCEoLwSW (aka data_sub) & ESCEoLwSW (aka data_all), the row im testing shows up in the same row in both data object. so basically there's no problem viewing the value when viewing them as object in RStudio, its just the value changed when printed out on the console. this has happened when its a date format object. they may appear to be in date format when viewed from RStudio, but when you print onto console, they are in their respective numerical values

Comment: i can upload some sample data for you to play with; here's the link to some sample data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwIbultIWxeVby1vRTgxN0xDeFU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Generally a very unwise idea to use dataframe names in the second argument to subset. The question is very confused at this point becaust the object names do not match what you dput in the comment present. You should NOT post data in comments but rahter use the edit facility.

Comment: Even with that data, I just can't seem to replicate the problem properly. For me it works fine. I'm really not sure what is causing any of this :\

Comment: @Laterow hi sorry. i've changed up my data a bit. please see the original post for the corrected sample data! and i will also change my code accordingly. thank you!!!

Comment: @42- okay will change that! thanks for the suggestion